# qemuでuefiアプリケーションを動かす方法について

Tags: qemu

はじめまして
Ubuntu上でqemuでuefiアプリケーションを動かそうとしていますが方法がわかりません。
試した方法は次の通りです

1. file hello.efi

   > hello.efi: PE32+ executable (EFI application) x86-64 (stripped to external PDB), for MS Windows
2. dd if=/dev/zero of=usb.img bs=512 count=200

   > 200+0 レコード入力
   >   200+0 レコード出力
   >   102400 バイト (102 kB) コピーされました、 0.00105836 秒、 96.8 MB/秒
3. gdisk usb.img

   > Command (? for help): n 
   >     : 
   >   Hex code or GUID (L to show codes, Enter = 8300): EF00
   >   Command (? for help): w
   >   Do you want to proceed? (Y/N): y
4. gdisk -l

   > Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   >   1              34             166   66.5 KiB    EF00  EFI System
5. sudo losetup --offset 34 /dev/loop0 usb.img
6. mkdosfs /dev/loop0
7. sudo mkdosfs /dev/loop0

   > Loop device does not match a floppy size, using default hd params
8. mount /dev/loop0 /tmp/Buzz/
9. mkdir -p /tmp/Buzz/EFI/BOOT
10. cp hello.efi /tmp/Buzz/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
11. qemu-system-x86_64 -bios OVMF.fd -m 512 -cpu kvm64 -vga cirrus -hdb usb.img

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

私自身の質問の答えになりませんが、イメージではなく、実際のUSBメモリを使うことでefiアプリケーションを動かすことにしました。 参考までに手順を残しておきます

1. gpartedでfat32のパーテーションを作成
2. そのパーテーションにbootable,espのフラグをつける
3. そのパーテーションをマウントする(例えば、/dev/sdc1を/tmp/buzなどに)
4. /tmp/buzにefiプログラムを置く
5. qemu-system-x86_64 -bios OVMF.fd -usb /dev/sdc実行

以上です。ありがとうございました。